# Should I have most of my code in the with statement? Python

Tags: python, with-statement, conceptual

I've noticed that most tutorials showing how to use a with statement they keep most of their code in that statement. Is there a benefit to keeping it open (other than accessing the contents again) rather than pulling the contents into a list and closing it as soon as possible.

Example:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    list = f.readlines()
    # Code that does stuff with list
# end of with open

# vs

with open('file.txt') as f:
    list = f.readlines()
# end of with open
# Code that does stuff with list
```

Comment: Have you tried it and seen what the difference might be?

Comment: @Paranaboy, by the way f.readlines() results a list, but you shouldn’t use the keyword list here as a variable.

Comment: Once you are done using `f` then there is no point to keeping the file open.

Comment: @Cow I just used the time module to test to see if there was any speed difference. There doesn't seem to be a huge difference. Other than that I'm not really sure what to look for.

Comment: @Hermann12  Thank you for the reminder! I do know that, I was just using it for the purpose of trying to convey my thoughts to something more tangible.

Comment: @chepner Are there any sources I could look into to understand more about the file being buffered? I'd like to learn more about it being memory efficient.

Comment: I mean, it's more efficient because the entire file *isn't* being read into memory at once. A very simpler version would be `def __next__(self): return self.readline()`, but I think it's a little more complicated. Essentially, it's reading a fixed-size chunk from disk (probably 4k or whatever the block size is), then returning lines from that chunk as requested; when the buffer is exhausted before finding another newline, another chunk is read.

Comment: When you say "closing *it* as soon as possible" you mean "closing the with-statement block" not "closing the open file object `f`". But FYI one of the many reasons people use a with-statements is because when it ends, its `__exit__()` method implicitly calls `close()` on the open file object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `with` statement is generally used to ensure *resources* are cleaned up as soon as possible. So as a general principal, keeping the `with` statement open  for the shortest time possible is best to keep resource usage low.

In your example, the *resource* is a open file, which has quite a low overhead. But some context managers (e.g. a database connection) might represent much higher resource usage and benefit from early cleanup.

This is only a general principal though, and legitimate reasons exist to keep the `with` statement open longer. For example:

**Resource reuse**

If you needed to use the file later in your code, keeping it open would avoid having to re-open it later.

**More efficient resource use**

In your example, you're reading the whole file into memory as a list. If you only needed to process each line once, you might benefit from a longer `with` statement and an iterative approach.

In other words, rather than this, (which loads the whole file into memory):

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

Use this (which only loads one line at a time into memory):

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

In the second example, the `with` statement is held open longer, but the memory usage should be lower.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the kind of information I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

In Python, the with statement replaces a try-catch block with a concise shorthand. More importantly, it ensures closing resources right after processing them. So when you process your txt file(for this example) you don't need to keep it open after processing. Because your `list` is generated and saved. It's much more efficient for big files to prevent high memory usage. If the file is not external there is no need for with statement because it's already in this program.

What is internal and external format?
Internal format: The internal format is the way the data is stored in the program.
External format: The external format is the way the data is stored in files.
For this example `file.txt` is external file and `list` is internal.